# Infuse places sms contact in call logs

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, calllog

I'm searching for an answer that others have also asked, but nobody has yet answered...

I have a Samsung Infuse.  It displays `SMS-Text` message information in the call log.  I have written code to list the call logs, however the code not list those messages.  Any idea how to get both the calls AND the SMS text log listed like the phone does?

I have tried managedQuery and getContentResolver().query with the URI of "content://call_log/calls".  This indeed returns the PHONE CALLS from the log, but skips the SMS-Text entries that exist when I review my call log.  Interestingly the phone shows different icons by each entry (so it knows which entry is from a call and which is from an SMS) and it also provides the `MENU OPTION` to filter the display by:

`All Logs`

`Missed Calls`

`Dialed Calls`

`Received Calls`

`Sent Messages`

`Received Messages`

This makes me think that it might just be a `different type` of log entry, but that does not seem to match what is returned by the queries.  It also makes me wonder if this device has it's own content provider for logs, as it seems this is unique to my device because the emulator does not put SMS contact information in the call log, nor does any of my friend's android devices.  I hate it and want to write an app that deletes SMS contact entries from my call log so that only phone call entries remain!  Note that because others have asked the question, I am not the only Samsung user that wants to automatically have SMS-texts deleted from their call log (app coming if we can figure out how to find them in the log!)

Thanks for any help...

Frank